# Получение знака «сыщик»

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Не могу понять, почему не получил знак «сыщик».

Правка была внесена в это [сообщение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/279214/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0), со сроком давности > 6 месяцев. При этом в списке правок кол-во увеличилось на 1 и в шкале знака «археолог» стало 1/100. А «сыщика» нет.

Почему такой беспредел?

Comment: Подождите до завтра) во многих знаках есть задержка.